# Plugins ou ferramentas para criar posts de blog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webdesign

Pessoal tenho um blog pessoal e vou criar a sessão onde crio os posts, queria saber se tem algum plugin ou ferramenta que não dependa de nenhuma linguagem server side onde eu crio o post, usando aqueles botões de estilização como no word e ele me retorna o html para eu só guardar no banco.

Alguém conhece algum?

Comment: [Tiny mce](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php)

Comment: [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Já utilizei esse plugin, talvez te ajude http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 2):

Você está procurando por um editor de texto [WYSIWYG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), existem várias recomendações de editores, em diversas linguagens e formatações diferentes, recomendo que busque por `html wysiwyg` no [google](/questions/tagged/google) e compare todas as ferramentas disponíveis para abalizar qual delas cabe melhor para a sua necessidade.

Mas caso queira um exemplo de uma ferramenta lhe indicarei o [tinymce](/questions/tagged/tinymce), pois além de ser de fácil instalação ele é completamente customizável.

No exemplo abaixo pode-se ver como utilizar o modo `basic`:

```
<!-- Place inside the <head> of your HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
 });
</script>

<!-- Place this in the body of the page content -->
<form method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

O código acima retorna um editor [assim](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php)

Podemos ver também todas as opções do modo `full`, onde você pode customizar todos os pluguins e botões do editor:

```
<!-- Place inside the <head> of your HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#elm1",
    theme: "modern",
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
 }); 
</script>

<!-- place in body of your html document -->
<textarea id="elm1" name="area"></textarea>
```

O código acima retorna um editor [assim](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

Também possibilita você habilitar a edição `inline`, editando diretamente no conteúdo, sem precisar ir à tela de edição da página:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "h1.editable",
    inline: true,
    toolbar: "undo redo",
    menubar: false
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<h1 class="editable">Editable header</h1>

<div class="editable" style="width:100%; height:550px">
This is an editable div element element.
</div>
```

O código acima retorna um editor [assim](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php)

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa interessante que foge da mesmice dos editores WYSIWYG seria o [Stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io)

Você cria e salva documentos localmente, no browser, com *live preview*, suporte a HTML, [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) e [Github Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), backup sincronizado com Google Drive e Dropbox e publicação automatizada do documento redigido no Blogger, Dropbox, Gist, Github, Google Drive, SSH Server, Tumblr e WordPress.

Customizável, com atalhos de teclado, *templating* básico e funcionalidades [extensíveis](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/doc/developer-guide.md#developer-guide).

Vale a pena conferir